# Question about objects

Tags: c#, .net, object

Hey guys, i'm having some trouble with this:

In the object "consumer" i need to do a validation for the property Nit.

But i don't know where to put this validation.
Do i have to put it where i set the value,
In a public function to validate the content before setting the value,
or a method inside the object "validateNit"

I'm still learning and i have that doubt.

Ty so much for your help, and sorry about the crappy English.

Comment: What programming language are you talking about?

Comment: Is there a specific language this pertains to? Also, could you maybe use fewer line breaks? The formatting of your question seems more appropriate for a haiku. ;-P

Comment: Yeah sry, im programming on C#, and sry but i dont know how to structure the question in english.  i see a joke about "how many programmer do you need for changing a light bulb"... so i think the best choice is to make the method validateNit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the property is set just once on initialization, then validate it during object initialization, with a method validateNit. if it can be set/modified at any time with, say, a setNit(newNit) method, you can call validateNit() from setNit().